# How to add timeout using pika 1.1.0?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I have been using pika 0.12.* for a while and I was used to adding timeouts using the following code.

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
...
connection.add_timeout(30, error)
...
```

Now I am migrating to use pika 1.1.0 the same `add_timeout` function doesn't seem to be present in the framework anymore.

However, in the documentation, I could find the function `remove_timeout` which suggests that I still can add a timeout to my code. 
Is it still possible to add timeouts using the pika lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `call_later` method. It was renamed from `add_timeout` in the `1.0.0` release.

Comment: I copied my code from the example in the manual at some early version, in which the `add_timeout` method is called on `SelectConnection`. I found, that I must call the `call_later` function on the connection's `ioloop`